# How to integrate install4j license key with Ant build script?

Tags: install4j

We bought the install4j license. Please let us know to integration of license key with Ant build script ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/ant.html

you can set the license key with the `license` attribute of the `install4j` ant task.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me,

```
 <taskdef name="install4j"
                   classname="com.install4j.Install4JTask"
                   classpath="/home/User/install4j6/bin/ant.jar"/>

          <target name="build-media">
            <install4j  license="License Key" projectfile="project.install4j" destimation="Destination Dir"/>
             <variable>If Any<variable>
             <variable>If Any<variable>
          </target>
```